# How does the make utility resolve symbols/targets

Tags: linux, makefile

I am a newbie to make concept, i want to how does the make resolve symbols/target, does it generate some kind of symbol table mapping. Because we can declare the dependency targets before the main target and still it works. I know the general working of make utility but any help regarding internal working will be appreciable.

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Reading-Makefiles